# How to make asp.net core rc2 (.net framework) work with EF 7 and .net 4.61

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have created an asp.net core RC2 (.NET 4.61 framework) project.

Then I have created another "DataProvider" nuget class library (.NET core) with Entity Framework references and changed the `framework` in the `project.json` settings to `"net461":{}`.

The reason why I did not create a common c# class library because it has no project.json but I need that to setup stuff like:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "type": "build",
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final"
    }
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "imports": [ "portable-net451+win8" ],
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final"
    }
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "net461": {
      "buildOptions": {
        "emitEntryPoint": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The DataProvider project has my DbContext class.

Thus I go to the command line to the DataProvider directory and execute:

```
dotnet ef migrations add Init
```

Then I get this error:

```
This preview of Entity Framework tools does not support targeting class library projects in ASP.NET Core and .NET Core applications. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=798221 for details and workarounds.
```

I do NOT want to put my DbContext into the asp.net core rc2 project !!!

I clicked that link to find more about that workarounds, but there is actually nothing helpfull until I found that link:

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/blob/master/docs/cli/dotnet.rst

Here are 2 workarounds introduced due to this error I had before:

**workaround 1** did **not** work (*"To make the project a .NET Core App, add the "netcoreapp1.0" framework to project.json along with the other settings in the sample below:"*)

This is how I changed then the `project.json`

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [ "portable-net451+win8" ],
      "buildOptions": {
        "emitEntryPoint": true
      },

      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.0-*"
        },
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
          "type": "build",
          "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final"
        }
      },
      "tools": {
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
          "imports": [ "portable-net451+win8" ],
          "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

=> Because after many nugets get installed and I rebuild then I also have to add a program.cs which I added etc.. Then I rerun the "dotnet ef migrations add Init" on the CMD getting this error: `No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"`

**workaround 2** did **not** work: (*"To make a desktop .NET app, ensure you project targets "net451" or newer (example "net461" also works) and ensure the build option "emitEntryPoint" is set to true."*)

=> Because I get compile exception, that program.cs has no Main method.

Ok, I have a class library this has never a program.cs ... Then I added the program.cs with the static Main method. Now the project compiles, but when I rerun the "dotnet ef migrations add Init" on the CMD I get the same error as before !!!

What should I do to make the execution of "dotnet ef migrations add Init" work?

Answer (score 2):

The CMD error that you're seeing is a **bug** (See #[4797](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4797), #[1858](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/1858), #[4555](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4555), #[5392](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5392)).

I managed to overcome this error during my migration to RC2 by restarting my computer (Fancy, I know). It seems to be fixed in the internal feed though, there's also a PR in #1858.

Comment: I restarted my pc many times, nothing changed. Seems the most important issue you missed ;-) => https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3117#issuecomment-222259502 This will bit fixed though... to the RTM version which should come end of june :-/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this workaround - [Dotnet EF Migrations for ASP.NET Core](http://benjii.me/2016/05/dotnet-ef-migrations-for-asp-net-core/)

Comment: What a dude is that blog guy? copy/paste the workarounds from Microsoft pffhhhh.... and those workaround do not even worked see above. Here is the original link: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/blob/master/docs/cli/dotnet.rst

Comment: Haha, I hope it's not that bad :) I changed the workaround slightly as I had to put the .net version and buildoptions at the root level, instead of underneath the frameworks node. It works for my migrations class library. If anyone needs help feel free to tweet me.

Comment: @BenCull Hey Ben fine that you found here :P afair I have my stuff like yours but I will check again tomorrow and change my comment accordingly here.

Comment: @BenCull I tried your blog post again which is my workaround 1 (see above) and for me it does not work, I can also not imagine that it worked for you because of: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3117#issuecomment-222259502